# 'python' is not a recognised command in CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, installation, cmd

I have an issue with my current Python setup.

Now, my environment variables are all correctly setup(been working fine for a couple of years) and the Python variable is also added to the PATH.

However, recently all of a sudden, it stopped being recognized in terminal(**CMD, powershell as well as Git BASH**) while at the same time, it works perfectly in the integrated terminals of text editors as well when I open CMD/PowerShell/Git Bash from VSCode instead of opening it directly.

This issue popped up without me interfering with the environment variables/ installing any other python installation.

[P.S. I have Python 3.6 and 3.9 installed and use text editors including VSCode, atom]

Comment: You should be able to see what happens with [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). But if the application works when you give the full path, then the problem is in PATH.

Comment: You are essentially asking for a diagnosis of your specific Operating System and software setup, without providing it. Unless you provide all of that information to us, or on a more appropriate platform, we can only provide guesses. Also, as we are unaware of which 'existing ones' you've viewed in your own research, we really cannot determine which solutions are untried by you. Please use the [edit] facility to provide sufficient information for us to assist you with an actual reproducible issue. Thank you

Comment: I would start with `where python.exe`. Then, depending on what that yielded, I might do `echo %path%` and eyeball the results. Or do `FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN ( ;dir /b "c:\program files\python36\python.exe"; ) DO @echo %~dpn$PATH:i `  and expect to see `C:\Program Files\Python39\python` because that should take precedence (on my machine anyway: other way around if you expect 3.6 to be first). Substitute backquotes for `;` in this command. They are SO metacharacters so I can't put them in a comment.

Comment: @BoarGules, the simplest way to determine the location of the default `python` executable used under `%PATH%`, if the user uses `python.exe`, would be `for %g in (python.exe) do @echo %~$path:g`. Of course this does not determine if  a file named python.exe, exists in the current directory, which would take precedence. If the end user is lazy, and cannot be bothered to use `python.exe`, and decides instead to use `python`, then the first result displayed by `%systemroot%\system32\where.exe python` will be what's used in those scenarios. That could, as it depends upon `%PATHEXT%` not be an EXE.

Comment: @Compo The intent was to diagnose a problem with the PATH variable, not to discover the default Python executable. OP indicates the location is already known, is correct, has not been moved or reinstalled recently, and can be found by cmd and Powershell when launched from inside VScode.

Comment: @BoarGules, you were speaking about what should take precedence, I was simply expanding upon that with a little more accuracy. Also, the OP said something, but has not provided any proof of such, and therefore we cannot make a diagnosis. Their question is lacking in sufficient detail, and cannot be answered without guessing. This site is for technical programming questions, not OS/software configuration fixes, or guessing games.